# Sort Array of Maps by more than one value

Tags: scala, sorting, multiple-columns

For instance, how can I sort this Array by **points** and **name** using a function like Scala's `sortWith`:

```
val arr = Array(
  Map("name"->"A","points"->"10"),
  Map("name"->"B","points"->"9"),
  Map("name"->"C","points"->"8") )
```

Sort by points only:

```
arr.sortWith(_.get("points").getOrElse("0").toLong < _.get("points").getOrElse("0").toLong)`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **sortBy** function:

```
arr.sortBy( ( m: Map[String, String] ) => ( ( m.getOrElse( "points", "0" ).toLong, m.get( "name" ) ) ) )
```

This above snippet will sort by points first (smallest to largest), then to break any ties then alphabetically by the name (asc).

The function "comparator" passed in to the **sortBy** function may return a value that is a tuple (one or more discriminators to sort by). So in this case, I'm returning ( points, name )